# Fetching Chainlink's Oracle Private Key

Tags: blockchain, chainlink

I have setup a chainlink oracle on kovan as well as bnb testnet, and have funded both of them with ETH and BNB. Now I would like to move towards mainnet deployment but I still haven't found a way to fetch my oracle's private key so that I can reclaim my ETH and BNB on mainnet once the job of oracle is completed. I have searched about it and found that the private key is stored encrypted in some keys.json file but I am unable to find such file. I can only find a secrets file but not sure how to fetch the private key from that. Any help would really be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to use some of the tasks on the CLI for the ETH? https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/wiki/Command-Line-Options

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92088/how-do-i-withdraw-ether-from-my-chainlink-node